# Using an absolute path in a vue-router route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue app, I have the following routes (among others)

```
  {
    path: '/event/:eventId?',
    name: 'event',
    component: EventTask
  },
  {
    path: '/terms-and-conditions',
    name: 'terms-and-conditions',
    component: TermsAndConditions
  }
```

A link to the terms and conditions is shown in the footer, so may be accessed from any page. If I'm on the event route, and I click on the link to the terms and conditions

```
<router-link to="terms-and-conditions">
  <v-btn text>Terms of Use</v-btn>
</router-link>
```

The browser navigates to the path `/event/terms-and-conditions` instead of `/terms-and-conditions`. How can I make this an absolute route, so it always navigates to `/terms-and-conditions`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the name of your route

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'terms-and-condition' }">
   <v-btn text>Terms of Use</v-btn>
<router-link>
```

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to